# Carousel image changes with category in ember js

Tags: ember.js

I have designed an image carousel and navbar above it with different a category. The plan is when one of the categories are clicked the images in carousel change. The category are fetched from the backend and displayed in navbar. How do I relate it to the carousel for each category?

I am using ember js(1.13.0).

application.hbs

```
<ul>
{{#each result in model.results}}
<li><a href="" {{action 'carousel' result}}>{{result.gallery_name}}</a></li>
{{/each}}
</ul>
```

controller.js

```
export default Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    actions:{
        carousel:function (result) {
         console.log(result.get('gallery_name'));
        }
    }
});
```

model.js

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  results: DS.attr()
});
```

server result (json)

`results:[{name:abc,url:http://google.com},{name:acd,url:google.com}.....]`

Comment: You need to provide your code so that we can help you. By simply posting question doesn't make sence

Comment: i am getiing error "Uncaught TypeError: result.get is not a function" in controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You JSON is

```
results:[{name:abc,url:http://google.com},{name:acd,url:google.com}.....]
//your Model
export default DS.Model.extend({
  results: DS.attr()
});
```

1. I donot see "gallery_name" in your json.
2. I donot see name / gallery_name defined in your model